# How do I reinitialize bootstrap tooltip so that the text is translated when language is changed using i18n?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, tooltip, i18next

I'm using bootstrap tooltips and my page is in 2 languages. I'm using jquery i18n to change the language. I need to change tooltip text when language is changed.

I have succcessfully changed the title attribute for my inputs with `data-i18n=[title]inputhelper`and I can see it changes because the default html title shows different text than my bootstrap tooltip.

```
function updateContent() {
  $('.content').localize();
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('update');
}
```

This is what I tried to do to update the tooltip element so it would have the new text but it didn't work.

Now I think what I need to do is reinitialize tooltips but can't quite figure out where exacty and how exactly I would do that. Any advice on how to translate those bootstrap tooltips with i18n would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** this is how I know that the title attribute value changes: [image: title attribute value change]

**EDIT2:** I was actually able to figure it out after some trial and error. Here's how I did it:

```
 function updateContent() {
  $('.content').localize();
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose');
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day with the EDIT2.